# Find process causing io

Tags: storage, performance

I've been having some serious performance problems with my fairphone (wait times of 1 minute or more before apps open or switching apps, and general lack of responsiveness).

I installed System Monitor Lite, and it shows storage I/O maxing out (screen shot below).

Are there any tools I can use to trace which process(es) this I/O is coming from?

[image]